# Android View orientation constants

Tags: android, android-view, android-orientation

I've added orientation attribute to my custom view, and i want to compare it's value with predefined [constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#orientation), but not with simple numbers (what if values will be changed). R.attrs.orientation is other value. Where i can "take" this values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what your question is, but don't worry about the constants changing. As long as you use the constant and not [its value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) you'll be fine if they change.

Comment: You are right, i don't want to use "Magic number", i want some android constant instead.

Answer (score 3):

you can find it here: [Config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html)

Comment: I think, this class is applicable for taking all device configuration information. But i need constants names for android:orientation attribute values.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE something like this?

Comment: Yes, values are the same, but this constants are for screen orientation, not current view (This includes both user-specified configuration options (locale and scaling) as well as device configurations (such as input modes, screen size and screen orientation)). That's why i don't want to use them.